# Add custom user roles spree 1.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I am using **spree 1.3.1** and **Devise gem** for authentication and i need to add a **user_role** called as "**partner**" who can see orders in admin area but can't create/edit/update/delete any of the orders.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what else have you tried and where are you getting problem in roles based views?

Comment: i followed this link http://s182.codeinspot.com/q/1784296

Answer (score 1):

Having `app/models/partner_ability.rb` file.

Then use the following role based `read` permissions for role `partner` -

```
class PartnerAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.has_role? "partner"
      can :read, Product
    end
  end
end
```

Also add the following after that to  `config/initializers/spree.rb` -

```
Ability.register_ability(PartnerAbility)
```

Comment: i have already tried this but this can't give access to the admin area where user(partner) can see all orders. Actually i want to give him access for http://localhost/admin/orders index page

Answer (score -1):

```
In db/seed.rb file we can directly add admin user in spree..

for example 


puts 'SETTING UP DEFAULT USER LOGIN'

user1 = User.create! :title => 'Mr', :first_name => 'Jack', :last_name => 'Jackson', :email => 'jack@g.com', :password => '123qwe', :password_confirmation => '123qwe', :phone => '123452345'
puts 'New user created: ' << user1.first_name

user2 = User.create! :title => 'Mr', :first_name => 'Sev', :last_name => 'Raj', :email => 'sa@g.com', :password => '123qwe', :password_confirmation => '123qwe', :phone => '123452345'
puts 'New user created: ' << user2.first_name

puts 'New user created: ' << user4.first_name

user2.add_role :admin
```