# Creating an index page for supplier using Spree in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am using `spree_drop_ship` as an extension to build my application.

Does spree provide an interface for the supplier to login and see what his products,orders, or shipments are?

I have checked in `Supplier controller` there was no index function defined.

Comment: There is just an admin side to spree , if that's what you are talking about . You can set multiple admins .

Comment: Also you can override controllers and views using deface

Comment: @Caffeine Coder - My requirement after I create a supplier.

Comment: @Caffeine Coder  -  My requirement is that ,after I create a supplier, If the Supplier Logs in then he should only be able to see the products,orders under him. I am trying to upload products from a rake task, so each product will be linked to one supplier. In my case if a supplier Logs in then he should only see products under him not other suppliers. I know that this  could be accomplished using changes in controller and views, but is there anything which spree provides ready made for this? . If I set up multiple admins then everybody will be able to see all the  products and orders.

Comment: Absolutely , you can set different roles for users and check the role the user has each time he logs in . Tou can read more on it here - https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/authentication.html

Comment: More on it here too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338237/add-custom-user-roles-spree-1-3-1

Answer (score 2):

Taking inputs from the answer i linked in the comments , your code would be something like this

```
class SupplierAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.has_role? "supplier"
      can :read, Product
    end
  end
end
```

And ofcourse adding this to spree.rb initializer ,

```
Ability.register_ability(SupplierAbility)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .Will Definitely work on your references.

Comment: @Shakthi now you can accept this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `spree_marketplace` along with `spree_drop_ship` to get that extra functionality for supplier to add and edit products.